# XML feed data's are importing with the XML tags

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, feeds

I have created a XML feeds by the [tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/919448), but I have found one problem that the XML tags are also appending to data, ie title, description and salary tags are also there
The output is following

```
<title>Drupal Developer 100</title>

<description>A job creating applications with Drupal.</description>

salary:
<salary ccy="usd">60,000</salary>
```

The output shows like below, I want to remove `<title>`
[image]

**EDIT 1**

I get the answer by [this](http://drupal.org/node/1045026) tutorial, just uncheck the check-box under **"Select the queries you would like to return raw XML or HTML"** in **XPath XML parser settings**

Answer (score 1):

You could use -

> tag/text()

This worked for me. It retrieves all the data that matches the tag.